# What does file:// prefix mean when reading a file

Tags: java

I see two types of references to files, example: I have a file called a.txt located at: /tmp/a.txt

The two reference types are either pointing to it directly: "/tmp/a.txt", or adding a "hdfs,local,file" prefix to the file. I am wondering what is the meaning of using this prefix. The case of `hdfs` is trivial but what is the meaning of using the others? example:

```
    String file = "/tmp/a.txt";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.out.println(fileInputStream.available());

    file = "local://tmp/a.txt";
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.out.println(fileInputStream.available());

    file = "file://tmp/a.txt";
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.out.println(fileInputStream.available());
```

The absolute path returned a result, the `local` and `file` paths threw FileNotFoundException

Comment: it is a protocol, thus, a URL is needed. Either do `file://localhost/tmp...` or `file:///tmp...`

Comment: Its a uri-format. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

Comment: Which means  it (file://tmp/a.txt ) will work only on FTP Protocol works.

Answer (score 3):

`file://` is protocol that refers to files on local network. Unlike `http://` that refers to the resources via http request.

See more [File URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) 
More [File URI Slashes issue](http://wiki.eclipse.org/File_URI_Slashes_issue)

You can use `file` prefix, but you need to convert it to a legal path:

```
String path = "file:///tmp/a.txt";
URI uri = new URI(path);
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(uri));
```

Comment: I like the code, but `file://` can refer to files on remote maches as well.

Comment: @Major fixed local machine to local network. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143141/what-does-file-prefix-mean-when-reading-a-file/55143231#comment97026761_55143141), the prefix `file://` is part of a URI scheme, often used in webbrowsers.  What it does is state that the object should be treated as a file.  The `file` can be a local or remote file.  Not every `File` handling api recognizes these prefixes.

Comment: It isnt spefic for webbrowsers. Its a defined standard to adress any kind of ressources.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to make it more clear that it's not just for webbrowsers.

Answer (score 0):

The File [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) does not support prefixes for the `pathname` parameter. That is the reason why the usage of prefixed `pathname` results in `FileNotFoundException`.

The JDK classes [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) supports the usage of prefixes such as in `file://ftp.yoyodyne.com/pub/files/foobar.txt` or in `http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/`.

Further, Spring supports prefixes such as `file:/` or `classpath:/` in its [resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) abstraction.

It is noteworthy that the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) on one hand, and the different resource abstractions (the Spring one, the URL and URI) on the other one,  that they represents quite different concepts.